# Sharing PHP file based sessions with django

Tags: php, python, django, session

I have been looking at ways to share PHP sessions with a Django installation on a common server.

I have looked into [django-php-bridge](https://github.com/winhamwr/django-php-bridge) and a variety of blog descriptions of the process such as this [one](https://web.archive.org/web/20171215205449/http://tech.myemma.com:80/more-about-going-from-php-to-python/).

Am I right in thinking that I need to modify my PHP code so that it uses a database session handler or is there a way to share these sessions using the default behaviour of filebased sessions under `/var/lib/php/session/` ?

It would be good if I did not have to patch every PHP file in an external code base in order to share the sessions with django.

Is it possible to enable `session.save_handler = memcache` in php.ini and configure django to read PHP's memcache session data?